# how to store in SOLR (mini) relational data

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, nosql, search-engine

My data set is title, description and tags.
I would like to store and index in the SOLR the tag_name and their relative tag_id.
As can be understood, each record has one title, one description bt many tag names + tag ids.

I guess I can store the tags as "some-tag-[id]" but his seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index tags and tags_id as multivalued fields and add in order.
The order is maintained so you can map them within the fields.

```
<field name="tags" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="tags_id" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Response -

```
<arr name="tags">
    <str>tag1</str>
    <str>tag2</str>
    <str>tag3</str>
</arr>
<arr name="tags_id">
    <str>id1</str>
    <str>id2</str>
    <str>id3</str>
</arr>
```

Comment: Great, I saw they are returned in same order, but was not sure this is hard.